# Java: Applet criteria

Tags: java, html, applet

So I'm having a tough time trying to understand the criteria that I need to follow in order for my Java program to be able to be embedded in HTML. Do I just have to extend my main class to the Applet class, or is there more that I have to do? Also, in every Applet example I've seen, it shows the code embedding a .class file, like so:

```
 <Applet Code="MyApplet.class" width=200 Height=100>
 </Applet>
```

Do I need to have all the .class files stored in a folder seperately, or does it just read the .class file specified from the compiled .jar?? I'm fairly lost here, if someone could clarify it would be much appreciated. Thanks

Comment: You really want to read the Java tutorial on Applets. The answers to your questions are all there, most of them on the first page: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/applet/

Comment: It is better to launch a `JFrame` based free-floating app. from a link on a web page using [Java Web Start](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/java-web-start/info).  Deploying an applet is more tricky.

Answer (score 2):

Definitely you can specify the jar class of jar file. be sure that you have put the jar in your class path and specify the full qualified path of the class file

refer for [how to create applet](http://www.realapplets.com/tutorial/HelloWorld.html)

Comment: *"put the jar in your class path"*  For an applet, that is done using the `archive` attribute of the `applet` element.